# How to put a vector of character strings of various length into a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a long vector that I want to put into a dataframe in R. Here is an example

```
vector<-c("1","John Doe","15%","2","Janet Doe","13%","3","Jack William Doe","10%")
```

I would like to have an output that would look like this

```
    Position      Names       Percentage
1        1         John Doe        15%
2        2        Janet Doe        13%
3        3 Jack William Doe        10%
```

I know the solution will involve data.frame() and probably strsplit() but the later splits the names that have variable length.

Comment: Why do you have such a vector? I suspect you should rather fix your data import step.

Comment: Data was imported that way following web scraping. It's obviously longer than the one provided in the example above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option is to convert to `matrix`, by specifying the number of columns (`ncol`), convert to `data.frame` and then change the column types with `type.convert`

```
out <- as.data.frame(matrix(vector, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE, 
      dimnames = list(NULL, c("Position", "Names", "Percentage"))), 
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
out[] <- lapply(out, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
out
#  Position            Names Percentage
#1        1         John Doe        15%
#2        2        Janet Doe        13%
#3        3 Jack William Doe        10%
```

As @nicola mentioned in the comments, the `type.convert` also introduced method for `data.frame` in recent `R` versions (checked in `R 3.6.0`).  So, the last line can be changed to

```
out <- type.convert(out, as.is = TRUE)
```

---

Or another option is to use `read.csv/read.table` after collapsing the 'vector' to a single string

```
read.csv(text= gsub("(([^,]+,){2}[^,]+),", "\\1\n",toString(vector)), 
    header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, col.names = c("Position", 
    "Names", "Percentage"), strip.white = TRUE)
#  Position            Names Percentage
#1        1         John Doe        15%
#2        2        Janet Doe        13%
#3        3 Jack William Doe        10%
```

which would ensure types to be converted accordingly based on the values instead of converting it later

Comment: Recent versions of R have also a  `type.convert` method for `data.frames`, so `type.convert(out,as.is=TRUE)` works just as fine.

Answer (score 4):

A tidyverse option. First split the vector according to a vector which repeats `1:3`, then map `parse_guess` onto the splits and output a data.frame, and finally add the desired names

```
library(tidyverse)

vector %>% 
  split(rep_len(1:3, length(.))) %>% 
  map_df(parse_guess) %>% 
  setNames(c('Position', 'Name', 'Percentage'))

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   Position Name             Percentage
#      <int> <chr>            <chr>     
# 1        1 John Doe         15%       
# 2        2 Janet Doe        13%       
# 3        3 Jack William Doe 10%
```

Answer (score 1):

Could also try:

```
data.frame(
  Position = vector[c(seq(1, length(vector), 3))],
  Names = vector[c(seq(2, length(vector), 3))],
  Percentage = vector[c(seq(3, length(vector), 3))]
)
```

Or make a function out of it to avoid lengthy repeats:

```
foo <- function(x, n) x[c(seq(n, length(x), 3))]

data.frame(
  Position = foo(vector, 1),
  Names = foo(vector, 2),
  Percentage = foo(vector, 3)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` to get the indices for each type of data, which you can use to subset the vector for each of your dataframe's variables:

```r
data.frame(Position = x[grep("\\d+$", x)],
           Names = x[grep("[^0-9%]", x)],
           Percentage = x[grep("%", x)]
)

#### OUTPUT ####

  Position            Names Percentage
1        1         John Doe        15%
2        2        Janet Doe        13%
3        3 Jack William Doe        10%
```